# Can Sphinx search engine do a NOT AND filter?

Tags: logic, sphinx

Suppose I have a Sphinx index with the following boolean attributes:

```
narrow
tall
```

I want to filter all the documents that are `NOT (narrow AND tall)`.

Can this be done with Sphinx?

If it makes any difference I'm using the Python `sphinxapi.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with attributes, you can create a 'virtual' attribute and then filter on that.

```
.setSelect("*, (tall=1)+(narrow=1) as tallnarrow")
.setFilter("tallnarrow", [2], true)
```