# Can Sphinx do a NOT AND filter with an IN clause?

Tags: python, logic, sphinx

This question is a more complex extension of [this simpler case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018778/can-sphinx-search-engine-do-a-not-and-filter).

In this instance, however, suppose I have an index with the following integer attributes:

```
category
type
```

Such that each document has one `category` ID and one `type` ID.

Suppose I also have a list of `category` IDs:

```
category_list = [1,3,5,7,9]
```

And a list of `type` IDs:

```
type_list = [1,2]
```

I want to filter all documents that are `NOT (IN category_list AND IN type_list)`

Once again, I'm using the Python `sphinxapi.py`.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar, just using the `IN()` function

```
.setSelect("*, IN(category,1,3,5,7,9)+IN(type,1,2) AS myfilter")
.setFilter("myfilter", [2], true)
```

Not sure the best python syntax to convert a list to the string, but that shouldnt be difficult.

Comment: Amazing. I used `ids_str = ",".join(str(x) for x in CATEGORY_IDS)`. Then `cl.SetSelect("*, IN(category,{0})+IN(type,1,2) AS myfilter".format(ids_str))` and `cl.SetFilter("myfilter", [0,1])` - here `[0,1]` is required because I want the  NOT filter. Thanks!